# VS Code cant import custom objects from salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm trying to create a custom form to insert a record for `Student` but I have a problem, VS or there is maybe something else, cant see my custom object named `Student`

```
import STUDENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Student';
import FIRST_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Student.Firstname';
import LAST_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student.Lastname';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student.Email';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student.Phone';
import ADDRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Student.Address';
```

First line, when I change to `Account` VS code suggest me a fields, but with `Student` it seems like VS code doesnt see custom object.

And errors when I try to deploy `lwc`:

```
 Invalid reference Student.Firstname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Address of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Lastname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Phone of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Email of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Firstname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Address of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Lastname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Phone of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Email of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Firstname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Address of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Lastname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Phone of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Email of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Firstname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Address of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Lastname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Phone of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Email of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Firstname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Address of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Lastname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Phone of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Email of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Firstname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Address of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Lastname of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Phone of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
          Invalid reference Student.Email of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js
```

And this is Student object:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to object's API name. Your custom object (like custom fields) most likely became `Student__c`.

As for autocomplete issues - try Ctrl+Shift+P "sfdx: refresh sobject definitions"

Comment: Same, I set `Student__c` as Object API as well for all other fields like filed name from object manager but `Invalid reference Student.First_name__c of type sobjectClass in file createStudent.js`

Comment: But it's still wrong? `Invalid reference Student.First_name__c` - it still says `Student`, not `Student__c`.

Comment: `import STUDENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c';
import FIRST_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c.First_name__c';` and so on

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use to use an ODBC connection to Salesforce which handles mapping the fields to a relational model. Then you can do it all with SQL.

Check out https://www.progress.com/odbc/salesforce as one option.